# java chain exception

Tags: java

i have question regarding chain exception

```
try{ } catch(Exception e) { throw new SomeException(); }
```

if i do like this
my eclipse will prompt error at line throw new SomeException();
stating "unhandled exception"
and i must put something like

```
try{ } catch(Exception e) {
                            try{ throw new SomeException(); } catch(Exception e){} 
                           }
```

why must do like this
because tutorial that i read .example http://java.sys-con.com/node/36579 , does not have to do this

Comment: Be aware that in most cases if you don't know how to handle the exception it's better to just let it propagate. You really only need to chain exceptions if letting an exception propagate would expose implementation details to the caller.

Comment: That is not exception chaining.

Answer (score 8):

You'll need to declare that the method `throws` another exception, if the exception is a [checked exception](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/exceptions.doc.html#44121).

("The unchecked exceptions classes are the class RuntimeException and its subclasses, and the class Error and its subclasses. All other exception classes are checked exception classes." -- [Java Language Specification, Second Edition, Section 11.2](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/exceptions.doc.html#44121))

For example, rather than:

```
void someMethod {
    try {
        // Do something that raises an Exception.
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new SomeException();    // Compile error.
    }
}
```

A `throws` needs to be added to the method declaration:

```
void someMethod throws SomeException {
    try {
        // Do something that raises an Exception.
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new SomeException();    // No problem.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It depends if SomeException is a checked exception or not. If it is (it extends Exception but not RuntimeException) then you have to declare it on the method or throw a RuntimeException instead.

This is what your code should look like:

```
...) throws SomeException {
....
try {
 ....
} catch (Exception e) {
   throw new SomeException(e);
}
```

If some exception doesn't have a constructor which takes an exception, then do this:

```
throw (SomeException) new SomeException().initCause(e);
```

That way when the exception is ultimately caught, you know the root cause of the problem.

Answer (score 3):

your method must declare that it may throw that exception. so, you must add:

```
throws SomeException {
```

at the end of your method's header.

Comment: So you don't need the try/catch since it does add any value anyway.

Comment: the try/catch block is needed because he wants to catch any exception in the try block and throw SomeException instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add "throws SomeException" to your method declaration.  You need to specify any exception types that your method throws except for exceptions that descend from RuntimeException.